USB Wireless Adapter not showing except in "lsusb"
I've been helping my friend troubleshoot this issue and can't find a solution:
He's trying to install Cinnamon.
He has a USB wireless adapter with the brand name "Foktech".
The adapter isn't showing up in his settings.
It's also not showing in the output of ifconfig -a.
That's only showing "lo" and "enp4s0", so ethernet and localhost.
However, it IS showing up in the output of lsusb as a "realtek" device.
That's been established by running watch -n 1 lsusb and monitoring the output as he's inserted and removed the adapter a few times.
I've had him turn it off and on again, run service NetworkManager restart, etc, but that's not solved the issue.
I'll take a look in a moment, but given the brand name, even if I can find drivers for the adapter, I doubt they'll be compatible.
He doesn't have an ethernet cable, so a wired connection isn't an option.
I recall there being a command to add wlan0 as an interface that included "phy0", so I'm gonna dig that up and see if it's of any use for this situation.
Meanwhile, does anyone have any further recommendations or any questions that may provide additional insight?
Thanks in advance :)
EDIT:
Ok, so I've looked through and optimized the script you referred me to and sent it to my friend. All I can do now is wait for him to run it and send me the output file. I'll go through that and post any relevant information in another edit.

Realtek has made so many different WiFi chips that the vendor and product ID numbers from the lsusb output line referring to the wireless adapter are going to be essential in identifying the exact chip model and the correct driver for it. Be aware that some chip models simply don't have good drivers for Linux (yet?), or no drivers for Linux at all.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180 The script will tell you everything about your WiFi, especially which driver you have to find and install, maybe through the dkms, build-essential, ... psth.
